# adjust heights of div's - based on resolutions and items count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've a requirement where I have `3 panels`(`Chats, Groups, Channels`) in the left side panel and I need to `adjust their heights` based on the `resolutions` and also the `items` in that panels.

I will make `api calls` and get the `items` for that panels and `bind` them through `angular bindings`.

Please check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santhosh1248/cxcwLtgq/22/) I've prepared for a clear understanding.In this, I've also wrote some additional `media queries` and adjusted the `max-heights` for the `resolutions`.

Now, My actual requirement is :

1) If there are `no items` at all in all the 3 panels, then all panels should `collapse` which is already working.

[image: link]

2) If all the `3 panels` has `items more than its size`, then `scroll should appear` as the `output screen` which is already working.

[image: link]

3) If only `one panel has items`, then it should automatically `expand its size` like shown in the image in the

[image: link]  and same should apply to other panels as well.

4) Finally, if only `few items are available in the 2 panels` and `more items are present in the 3rd panel`, then it should show in the following way.

[image: link]

Actually, I thought of writing some `jquery after the api calls` based on the `items count` but that's kind of getting hard because I need to check the resolutions as well and also the items count in all the panels.

Is there any css way of achieving this?
at least, is there any article or something where I can follow and do this?
is jquery, the only way of doing this?

Comment: does this plugin help? http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Answer (score 0):

You could standardise it at 33.33333vh height then modify it using jQuery after the fact. It could get a little complex depending on how many exceptions you want to cater for but this unit will take care of the resolution differences and is supported by modern browsers.

In your jQuery you could work out the number of items in each panel as a percentage of the total and give each panel an appropriate height in vh - the label.

```
$(function() {
  var totalNumItems = $('.panel div').length;
  $('.panel').each(function() {
    setPanelHeight($(this));
  });

  function setPanelHeight(panel) {
    var numItems = panel.find('div').length,
    heightPercentage = (numItems / totalNumItems) * 100;
    /* calc -1.5em takes the label height into account */
    panel.css('height', 'calc(' + heightPercentage + 'vh - 1.5em)');
    panel.niceScroll();
  }
});
```

If there were no items in a panel, it would calculate its vh as 0 and as such collapse it.

Edit: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mattBBP/8vvcub3c/
This doesn't quite work because the area it's being displayed is not 100% of the viewport but this could be modified/offset / would not be a problem out of the fiddle.